# Declaring GnuplotHelper failed in ns3

Tags: c++, linux, gnuplot, ns-3

I want to use [GnuplotHelper](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/manual/html/data-collection-helpers.html#gnuplothelper) in ns3 to plot the results. even when I run ns3's default example [seventh.cc](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/seventh_8cc.html) I get the following error:

```
../scratch/congestion.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
../scratch/congestion.cc:173:1: error: ‘GnuplotHelper’ was not declared in this scope
 GnuplotHelper plotHelper;
 ^
../scratch/congestion.cc:180:1: error: ‘plotHelper’ was not declared in this scope
 plotHelper.ConfigurePlot ("Test","CongestionWindow vs. Time","Time (Seconds)","CongestionWindow","jpg");
 ^
../scratch/congestion.cc:181:81: error: ‘GnuplotAggregator’ has not been declared
 plotHelper.PlotProbe (probeName,probeTrace,"CongetionWindow","CongestionWindow",GnuplotAggregator::KEY_BELOW);
```

If I include "[gnuplot-helper.h](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/gnuplot-helper_8h.html)" I get an additional line and same error:

```
../scratch/seventh.cc:24:28: fatal error: gnuplot-helper.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I've installed gnuplot on my linux. What should I do? How can I declare Gnuplot helper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, did you install a gnu-plot-dev package or just gnuplot? Many distributions separate the ability to use libraries and the ability to develop against them.

If you are sure the include files are actually on your system somewhere (check both /usr/include and /usr/local/include/) you may need to add an additional directory level to your compiler search path (perhaps /usr/include/gnuplot/ but I am only guessing there).

Comment: Thanks. The error was in include. I should have included the directory ns3/.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#include "ns3/stats-module.h"
```